# Android Studio problemas con ScrollView

Tags: android-studio, scroll

tengo un problema. Tengo un scroll view que contiene texto y botones, la idea es a medida que se oprimen los botones vayan apareciendo los textos(los textos  los botones están invisibles y cuando se van apretando los botones cambian a visibles).
El problema es que al iniciar la aplicación puedo bajar y al estar los textos y los botones invisibles queda en blanco. Hay alguna forma de que no me permita bajar hasta que vayan apareciendo el texto y los botones?

Para que se entienda mejor les dejo el código para que lo prueben. Gracias

Este es el xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Texto1"
                    android:id="@+id/tv1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:id="@+id/rb1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="a" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:id="@+id/rb2"
                    android:onClick="b"
                    android:checked="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Texto2"
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:id="@+id/rb3"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="c"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="D"
                    android:id="@+id/rb4"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="d"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Texto3"
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="E"
                    android:id="@+id/rb5"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:onClick="e"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="F"
                    android:id="@+id/rb6"
                    android:onClick="f"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Texto4"
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="g"
                    android:id="@+id/rb7"
                    android:onClick="g"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="h"
                    android:id="@+id/rb8"
                    android:onClick="h"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Texto5"
                    android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Y este el codigo:

```
public class Main22Activity extends Activity {

TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5;
RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6, rb7, rb8;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);

    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);

    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    rb5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb5);
    rb6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb6);
    rb7=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb7);
    rb8=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb8);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main22, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void a(View view){
    rb2.setEnabled(false);
    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void b(View view){
    rb1.setEnabled(false);
    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void c(View view){
    tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb4.setEnabled(false);
    rb5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void d(View view){
    tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb3.setEnabled(false);
    rb5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void e(View view){
    tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb6.setEnabled(false);
    rb7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void f(View view){
    tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb5.setEnabled(false);
    rb7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void g(View view){
    tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb8.setEnabled(false);
}

public void h(View view){
    tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rb7.setEnabled(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que estas usando el modo invisible, que hace que la View sea "transparente" aunque sigue ocupando espacio. Para hacer que desaparezca por completo debes usar el modo "gone". En tu XML, sustituye todas las líneas

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

por

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Tal y como dice la documentación oficial:
INVISIBLE: this view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

GONE: this view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona como quiero gracias