# ¿se puede hacer un fragment con scroll vertical en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Es para un cuestionario en forma de lista, pero las preguntas inferiores a mi fragment no las puedo ver por que el fragment no tiene el scroll

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
tools:context=".FRPreguntas">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="535dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="137dp"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="30dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="444dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Prue"
    android:textSize="62dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp" />
```

`</FrameLayout>`

Comment: muestra tu codigo xml

Comment: lo pensaba hacer con un ScrollView pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación se cierra, estoy utilizando swipetabs

Comment: ¿Porque no creas un ListView o un RecyclerView para eso que quieres? Hay muchos tutoriales. Lo que quieres es repetir mucho una misma vista te ahorraría mas código.

Comment: aqui hay un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24558/android-studio-problemas-con-scrollview

Comment: gracias hermano!